# Access ACM from a lambda with no internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Pretty much the title. I have a lambda which is connected to a VPC with no internet access. We want to access a certificate which is hosted in ACM, is this possible at all ?

Usually to access other services like S3, DynamoDB in this model, AWS provides a VPC Interface/Gateway endpoint, but there isnt one for for ACM.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no VPC endpoint for ACM, you need a nat gateway for the resources in the private subnets to access the ACM via internet.